# There is operate the char and integer when I got the problems

Tags: c, issue-tracking

[image]

Even doing c char and int operating then why first we get the int value and put the "enter" enter also get the charcter.why is it?

i just want to know why it is goes to like that.

Comment: `scanf` puts decimal `10` (which is '\n'), then you sum `12` and `10` (as `char` is a normal integer type) and you get `22`

Comment: @Pathum Lakshan Use scanf( " %c", &c ); Pay attention to the leading space in the format string. It allows to skip white space characters.

Comment: Please always add text (code, error messages, input and output) as formatted text in your question. Don't show pictures as we cannot copy&paste them into the compiler.